# How to show infobox outside the map-canvas viewport (with a z-index higher than map)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want my infobox to be fully shown(cant use autoPan due to some reason) if not in map, then little bit outside map like what  [Redfin](http://www.redfin.com/) guys are doing....But I cant get it even after trying so many things.

Attached herewith two images to demonstrate my issue..The first one is from [Redfin](http://www.redfin.com/) what I want and the second one is my scenario which is default

![image]

[image]

The map pane seems to be maximum (floatpane) so no use of providing higher z-index to infobox.

Thanks..

Comment: Make your own div outside the map container. Place it where you want it on your page.  Put the infowindow content in it.

Comment: @geocodezip - Yes...I was thinking the same...but how can I get the screen position equivalent of the marker/cluster latlong in pixels since the infobox should point the marker/cluster?

Comment: [fromLatLngToContainerPixel(latLng:LatLng)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapCanvasProjection)?